# How to output an array of images upon each page refresh?

Tags: php

I have a PHP page with the following code:

```
<?php
$file_out = "image1.png"; // The image to return

if (file_exists($file_out)) {

   $image_info = getimagesize($file_out);

   //Set the content-type header as appropriate
   header('Content-Type: ' . $image_info['mime']);

   //Set the content-length header
   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_out));

   //Write the image bytes to the client
   readfile($file_out);
}
else { // Image file not found

    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 404 Not Found");

}
```

Each time the page refreshes, I'd like the image to change to a random image from the root directory: image1.png, image2.png. image3.png etc. What do I need to add to my code?

Comment: in the root directory, only image files exist?

Comment: Yes, other than the main php that this code is on